# Transmute works but mutate does not

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the dataset below along with other columns not shown here:

```
  v0102      v0103      child.below14 child.above14
1 31000010   1                      0             0
2 31000010   1                      0             0
3 31000010   1                      1             0
4 31000010   1                      1             0
5 31605621   1                      0             0
6 31605621   1                      1             0
7 31605621   1                      1             0
8 31605877   1                      0             0
9 31605877   1                      1             0
```

I want to groupby the first two columns and count the number of children below and above 14 years old. When I try with transmute, I get the expected answer:

```
df.pnad.mg %>% group_by(v0102, v0103) %>% transmute(children.below14 = sum(child.below14), children.above14 = sum(child.above14))

   v0102      v0103      children.below14 children.above14
 1 31000010   1                         3                0
 2 31000010   1                         3                0
 3 31000010   1                         3                0
 4 31000010   1                         3                0
 5 31605621   1                         2                0
 6 31605621   1                         2                0
 7 31605621   1                         2                0
 8 31605621   1                         2                0
 9 31605877   1                         1                0
```

However, when I switch from transmute to mutate, the output seems to ignore the group_by() verb:

```
df.pnad.mg %>% group_by(v0102, v0103) %>% mutate(children.below14 = sum(child.below14), children.above14 = sum(child.above14))

  v0102      v0103      children.below14 children.above14
1 31000010   1                      8092             7949
2 31000010   1                      8092             7949
3 31000010   1                      8092             7949
4 31000010   1                      8092             7949
5 31000010   1                      8092             7949
6 31605621   1                      8092             7949
7 31605621   1                      8092             7949
8 31605621   1                      8092             7949
9 31605877   1                      8092             7949
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you run `packageVersion("dplyr")`? I get your expected output using 1.0.2.

Answer (score 2):

The function you want is `summarize` not `mutate`.

```
df.pnad.mg %>% 
  group_by(v0102, v0103) %>% 
  summarize(children.below14 = sum(child.below14), 
            children.above14 = sum(child.above14))
```

When you use `mutate` it will calculate the sums, but it keeps all of the rows.

Using the nine rows of your data, this is the output I get:

```
`summarise()` regrouping output by 'v0102' (override with `.groups` argument)
# A tibble: 3 x 4
# Groups:   v0102 [3]
     v0102 v0103 children.below14 children.above14
     <dbl> <dbl>            <dbl>            <dbl>
1 31000010     1                2                0
2 31605621     1                2                0
3 31605877     1                1                0
```

If your desire is to keep all rows, then `mutate` should work. I cannot reproduce your mutate issue in `dplyr 1.0.2`. Here is my output for `mutate`:

```
df.pnad.mg %>% 
  group_by(v0102, v0103) %>% 
  mutate(children.below14 = sum(child.below14), 
         children.above14 = sum(child.above14))
# A tibble: 9 x 6
# Groups:   v0102, v0103 [3]
     v0102 v0103 child.below14 child.above14 children.below14 children.above14
     <dbl> <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>            <dbl>            <dbl>
1 31000010     1             0             0                2                0
2 31000010     1             0             0                2                0
3 31000010     1             1             0                2                0
4 31000010     1             1             0                2                0
5 31605621     1             0             0                2                0
6 31605621     1             1             0                2                0
7 31605621     1             1             0                2                0
8 31605877     1             0             0                1                0
9 31605877     1             1             0                1                0
```

If you want to create these new columns and drop the old ones, then `transmute` is what you do.

Comment: I want to create a new column with the number of children above and below 14 for each pair of (v0102, v0103). I don't believe summarize does that.

Comment: @GustavoRangel - This is exactly what summarize does.

Comment: Sorry If I am not being clear. Your anwser gives me a 3-row table, instead of the 9 I need to put them together with the original dataset.

Comment: @GustavoRangel - I cannot reproduce the issue you have with `mutate`. If `transmute` works, why not just use it?

Comment: I decided to reinstall dplyr (same version 1.0.4) and now I get the expected answer. Pretty weird, but thank you so much for your effort!

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved using [`across`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/across.html) in the following manner:

```
library("tidyverse")
dta <- read_delim(
    file = "id v0102      v0103      child.below14 child.above14
1 31000010   1                      0             0
2 31000010   1                      0             0
3 31000010   1                      1             0
4 31000010   1                      1             0
5 31605621   1                      0             0
6 31605621   1                      1             0
7 31605621   1                      1             0
8 31605877   1                      0             0
9 31605877   1                      1             0",
delim = " ",
col_types = cols(.default = col_integer()),
trim_ws = TRUE
)

group_by(dta, v0102, v0103, .add = TRUE) %>%
    mutate(across(
        .cols = starts_with("child"),
        .fns = sum,
        .names = "sum_{.col}"
    )) %>%
    ungroup()
```

### Results

```
# A tibble: 9 x 7
     id    v0102 v0103 child.below14 child.above14 sum_child.below14 sum_child.above14
  <int>    <int> <int>         <int>         <int>             <int>             <int>
1     1 31000010     1             0             0                 2                 0
2     2 31000010     1             0             0                 2                 0
3     3 31000010     1             1             0                 2                 0
4     4 31000010     1             1             0                 2                 0
5     5 31605621     1             0             0                 2                 0
6     6 31605621     1             1             0                 2                 0
7     7 31605621     1             1             0                 2                 0
8     8 31605877     1             0             0                 1                 0
9     9 31605877     1             1             0                 1                 0
```

## Notes

- `.names` argument takes [`glue`](https://github.com/tidyverse/glue) specification, it's worthwhile to reflect on that so the obtained names are meaningful
- `.add` in `group_by` makes sense if there are any other groups you may want to preserve.